# Can method inheritated from interface return another type that in interface?

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Lets say I have a code like this:

```
interface IObject
{
     IObject GetSomeObject();
}

public class ObjectClass : IObject
{
     IObject GetSomeObject()
     {
     // method implementation here
     }
}
```

Is there any way, that I make `GetSomeObject()` method of class `ObjectClass` make return `ObjectClass`, no `IObject`?

I know I can use it like this:

```
ObjectClass object1= someObject1.GetSomeObject() as ObjectClass;
```

But what I want to achieve is:

```
public class ObjectClass : IObject
{
     ObjectClass GetSomeObject()
     {
     // method implementation here
     }
}
```

Is it possible in that way?

Comment: Yes it is: just change your interface to: `interface IObject
{
     ObjectClass GetSomeObject();
}`

Comment: But still this is not a good idea your base class to knows about its successors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use generics:

```
interface IObject<T> where T : IObject<T>
{
    T GetSomeObject();
}

public class ObjectClass : IObject<ObjectClass> { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use an [explicit interface implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173157.aspx):

```
public interface IObject
{
     IObject GetSomeObject();
}

public class ObjectClass : IObject
{
    public ObjectClass GetSomeObject()
    {
        return this;
    }

    IObject IObject.GetSomeObject()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

This way, comsumers that access `ObjectClass` can call `ObjectClass GetSomeObject()`, whereas consumers that access an instance of this class through `IObject` can only call `IObject GetSomeObject()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics:

```
interface IObjectReturnable<T>
{
    T GetSomeObject();
}

public class ObjectClassRet : IObjectReturnable<ObjectClassRet>
{
    public ObjectClassRet GetSomeObject()
    {
        // method implementation here
        return new ObjectClassRet();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not bad, however `ObjectClassRet` does not realise `IObject` which was a requirement by the OP - _"But what I want to achieve is `public class ObjectClass : IObject {...}`"_